# Issue in ldap_explode_dn() when there is '#' symbol in the context name

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm passing in a DN with a leading `'#'` and getting back undef.  I
would expect to get it back escaped. Most special characters work fine,
but `"#"` doesn't.  Actually looks like a problem in the initial pattern
match in `ldap_explode_dn` E.g.:

a.     Original: `cn=#blr-infocus1,OU=resources,DC=foo,DC=com`

b.     Code: `$dnc = canonical_dn($dn, casefold => 'none')`

c.     Expected: `cn=\#blr-infocus1,OU=resources,DC=foo,DC=com`

d.     Returned: `undef`

This is `perl-ldap 0.33` with `ldap.pm` version 0.16.

Pls let me know if there is any work around or fix for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The value provided as a distinguished name: `'#blr-infocus1,OU=resources,DC=foo,DC=com'` is not a legal DN. Values that begin with the octothorpe are assumed to be integers. 'l' is not a valid hexidecimal integer. See also [rfc4513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514).